# Need to know when it's a new day, i.e., when the time is 00:00:00

Tags: android

I think I read somewhere that there's a system event for when the time changes (each second?) but are there other levels of granularity such as when the hour changes?

I have a `TabActivity` for a 7 day TV Guide - the indicator for the first (leftmost) always shows 'Today' with the others showing a three-letter day (Mon, Tue, Wed etc) obviously depending on what the day is today.

What I'd like to do is have the activity 'know' when midnight comes so it pops up a 'Re-loading please wait...' `ProgressDialog` and adjusts the indicator on each tab and the associated tab contents.

Is there a built-in system event that can help or is `AlarmManager` my best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is probably `AlarmManager` with a `PendingIntent` that sends a broadcast.  Then just implement a `BroadcastReceiver` to catch the broadcast and update your app.  Personally, I've never heard of a built-in broadcast for time changes, but if there is one, you could always just use an if statement to find out if it's the next day.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I found the system broadcast (ACTION_TIME_TICK) it's actually every minute not every second as I thought. I've never used AlarmManager or BroadcastReceivers so it's all new territory that I need to look at closer.

Comment: My recommendation is to implement the BroadcastReceiver within the TabActivity itself.  That way it can call functions within the TabActivity class.  It makes things a little easier.

Comment: Thanks, I have a BroadcastReceiver working with ACTION_TIME_TICK now so it looks like I can get it to do what I need.